# How to access flashplayer using GET method Httpclient

Tags: java, flash, httpclient, htmlunit

how to access a shock-wave flash player which has the 
Content-Type: application/x-shockwave-flash

its a request get so i am using GET method of HttpClient .
any solution to access flash content through Httpclient?

or else is there any other way to access the same through html unit ?

Thanks!!

Comment: No !! i just need to play(buffer) the swf file !!

Comment: @zsxwing : its a flash player letting us to listen to songs !! 
its a swf file !! but when i retrieve the page through httpclient it does not access the same !!

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to do? Do you mean that you want to play the swf file by Java? or you want to extract the links of songs which this swf file plays?

Comment: @zsxwing i need to make the play of the song count !! i.e if i fetch the page for 10 times it should make count 10 for the play !! for that even if i have to make the song play , its not a biggie >>>

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the count is not done by Javascript or the html unit can execute javascript and make the count plus 1. So maybe the count is done by the swf file running in the Flash Player. In this situation, you must have a container like Flash Player to  execute the swf file.

You can try http://djproject.sourceforge.net/main/index.html. It providers a connection to the Flash Player.

But it's a really big library that makes it inappropriate to you.

If you only want to automaticly the count in this website, you can sniffer the web communication between the client and web server to find out the request which cause the count plus 1. After that, you can just construct the same request to web server.

Comment: Yes!! the count increases based on the number of times the song plays !! so for this i also tried selenium ide !! but i am facing problem with the proxy config in that !!

so i preferred Httpclient to do this !! but as you have mentioned should i need to have a container like Flash Player to execute the swf file ??